# Videocapture using IPcam and google colab

Tags: networking, video-capture, google-colaboratory

I have installed opencv-python and dlib. My area of interest is working on facial recognition. So basically trying to extract faces where in I have a ipcam or a webcam. I am not able to access the cam by however possible. The piece of code I am using is

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.43.1:8080/video')
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.43.1:8080/onvif/device_service')
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.43.1:8080/h264_ulaw.sdp')
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://192.168.43.1:8080/h264_pcm.sdp')
    print(cap.isOpened())
    while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    if ret is True:
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break
    # When everything done, release the capture
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The print statement is always false however I try
In my local windows machine it is working fine. Main purpose of using colab.research.google.com is that my machine doesn't support cmake properly for dlib and face_recognition

Answer (score 3):

The python code you're executing via Colab is being executed on a VM; there's no way for that Python process to (safely) communicate directly with a webcam on your local machine.

Comment: How about a video uploaded to drive and then using that as feed. I tried to find commands for that but I got to see only reading a csv file using pandas

Comment: There are samples on fetching a Driv file at https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=7taylj9wpsA2; those should hopefully get you unblocked?

Comment: All that I can see is uploading and downloading text files because the methods mentioned are also like "setcontentasstring" and to display "cat" But no commands on images other than csv and py files in collaboratory

Comment: It's still the same basic mechanism -- here's a sample of uploading and downloading bytes: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gmh21OrJL0Dv49z28soYq_YcqKEnaQ1X

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using public IP address helps open and capture video from the camera usiing CV.

Answer (score 0):

> because, whenever you run your code on colab, it runs on their server not on your local
>   machine. And whatever you have pasted is your local ip. which can be resolved only within your network.

1. First, you have to get your public ip by using `ipconfig` command
2. But, Actually, when you paste the url, google's servertries to
   render the video for you. But, your workstation in which the webcam
   feed available is behind your gateway. (your private network).
3. Which means that it is not accessible outside of your local network.
   Because, it is by default, due to avoid IP Exhausting & Objectively
   to provide security to your machine.

Still if you want to expose your machine to the outer world(which is risky). You can look for NAT. (Network Address Translation).

- You have to check with your ISP. whether you have static ip because
  usually whenever you switch your network on & off, a new dynamic ip
  is assigned to your machine. so, whenever you switch the network, you have to change the ip in the code.
- Take a look here on how to setup : [Link](https://medium.com/botfuel/how-to-expose-a-local-development-server-to-the-internet-c31532d741cc)

Answer (score 0):

As said by people, you can not access your IP webcam directly as Google colab runs on virtual machine. Here is what I did for accessing the webcam of my laptop.

```
def take_photo(filename='photo.jpg', quality=0.8):
  js = Javascript('''
    async function takePhoto(quality) {
      const div = document.createElement('div');

      const video = document.createElement('video');
      video.style.display = 'block';
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});

      document.body.appendChild(div);
      div.appendChild(video);
      video.srcObject = stream;
      await video.play();

      // Resize the output to fit the video element.
      google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(document.documentElement.scrollHeight, true);

      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
      canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
      div.remove();
      return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', quality);
    }
    ''')
  display(js)
  data = eval_js('takePhoto({})'.format(quality))
  resp = urllib.request.urlopen(data)
  image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
  image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  # return the image
  return image

# to capture an image
img = take_photo()
```

The take_photo() function uses javascript to access your webcam connected to your system. Hopefully it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngrok to make your IP to the public then you can access your camera by ngrok IP.

1. Install ngrok - https://ngrok.com/download
2. Use this by - ./ngrok http http://192.168.43.1:8080/video

It will generate ngrok IP which will be available for 12 hours.

You can use it by just passing in **cv2.VideoCapture(ngrok_ip)** this.